# Redis::TimeoutError while queuing a Resque Job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, rubygems, resque

Getting timeout error from Redis while queuing a Resque job.

Exception that is being thrown-

**Connection timed out**

> /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:90:in `rescue in _read_from_socket'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:83:in`_read_from_socket'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:75:in `gets'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/connection/ruby.rb:380:in`read'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:262:in `block in read'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:250:in`io'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:261:in `read'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:193:in`block (2 levels) in call_pipelined'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:192:in `times'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:192:in`block in call_pipelined'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:231:in `block (2 levels) in process'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:367:in`ensure_connected'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:221:in `block in process'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:306:in`logging'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:220:in `process'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:187:in`call_pipelined'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:157:in `block in call_pipeline'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:293:in`with_reconnect'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis/client.rb:155:in `call_pipeline'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-4.3.0.335/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/redis.rb:89:in`call_pipeline'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:2258:in `block in pipelined'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in`block in synchronize'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:58:in`synchronize'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-3.3.3/lib/redis.rb:2254:in `pipelined'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:471:in`namespaced_block'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/redis-namespace-1.5.3/lib/redis/namespace.rb:284:in `pipelined'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque/data_store.rb:119:in`push_to_queue'
>   /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/resque-1.27.4/lib/resque.rb:271:in `push'

Comment: Can you place the snippets of code that led to this error?

Comment: ``Resque.enqueue(RandomJob, random_params)``  caused this error.

Comment: If you really need your problem solved, you'd have to add more info. Please add the job and the random enqueue params